# What is difference between (1,2,3) vs [1,2,3] in python ?

Tags: python, numpy

In following code, shape of size & randm is same only, 1-D Array (3,)
Then why size=(3, 3, 2) & randm=[-1.10343097 -1.31819984  0.20597956]

Q.1 Why different bracket () vs []
Q.2 What is significant of each bracket () & []

```
 image = np.array([[[ 0.67826139,  0.29380381],
        [ 0.90714982,  0.52835647],
        [ 0.4215251 ,  0.45017551]],

       [[ 0.92814219,  0.96677647],
        [ 0.85304703,  0.52351845],
        [ 0.19981397,  0.27417313]],

       [[ 0.60659855,  0.00533165],
        [ 0.10820313,  0.49978937],
        [ 0.34144279,  0.94630077]]])

size = np.shape(image)
print (str (size))
print (np.shape(size))

randm = np.random.randn(3)
print (randm)
print (np.shape(randm))
```

Output-

```
(3, 3, 2)
(3,)
[-1.10343097 -1.31819984  0.20597956]
(3,)
```

Comment: () -> This is a tuple data structure, [] -> This is a list

Comment: An even better duplicate: [Python: what is the difference between (1,2,3) and \[1,2,3\], and when should I use each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983/python-what-is-the-difference-between-1-2-3-and-1-2-3-and-when-should-i-us)

Comment: That literally shows up if you copy paste your title into google... o_o

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: what is the difference between (1,2,3) and \[1,2,3\], and when should I use each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983/python-what-is-the-difference-between-1-2-3-and-1-2-3-and-when-should-i-us)

Answer (score 1):

`image` is a multidimensional `numpy` array.  It is defined via a nested list of lists (the brackets and commas).

`image.shape` is a tuple, and so displays with ().

The other answers, and the supposed duplicate, focus on Python's distinction between lists and tuples.  But this needs a numpy focused answer.

A simple 3d array:

```
In [244]: x = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]]])
In [245]: x
Out[245]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]])
```

You can get the shape as a property, or via a function call

```
In [246]: x.shape
Out[246]: (1, 2, 2)
In [247]: np.shape(x)
Out[247]: (1, 2, 2)
```

But the `shape` does not have a shape property itself.  `len(x.shape)` would work, since it is a tuple.

```
In [248]: (x.shape).shape
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-248-b00338a7f4bf> in <module>()
----> 1 (x.shape).shape

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

`np.shape(...shape)` is confusing.  `np.shape()` will first turn its input into an array (if it isn't already) and return the shape of that:

```
In [249]: np.shape(x.shape)
Out[249]: (3,)
```

So I wouldn't normally take this shape of a shape.  However it does demonstrate a key point.  `(3,)` is a 1 element tuple.  The `,` is important.  The shape tuple for an 0d array is `()`.

The next part makes a 3 element array

```
In [250]: np.random.randn(3)
Out[250]: array([ 2.06265058,  0.87906775, -0.96525837])
In [251]: _.shape
Out[251]: (3,)
In [252]: print(__)
[ 2.06265058  0.87906775 -0.96525837]
```

Again, a (3,) shape tuple.  The `str` display of an array uses the brackets, but omits the commas.  That helps distinguish it from a regular list.

(There is also an array type that displays with (), a structured array. But that's a more advanced topic.)

Answer (score 0):

The `()` notation means that the data type is of `tuple` while the `[]` denotes a `list`.

Additionally tuples use less memory and are immutable while lists are mutable.

Comment: I changed it after I realized I meant `tuple`

Answer (score 0):

```
(1,2,3) -Tuple
[1,2,3] -List
```

Read This for more information about [tuple and list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: @user2864740 `np.shape` returns a tuple.

Comment: Question asked what is difference between (1,2,3) and [1,2,3] So (1,2,3) is tuple and [1,2,3] list.

Comment: @PM2Ring Sure, but I could change the output of FooBaz to look the same :}

Comment: Just saying that such short answers leave a good bit to be desired.